# magento - adding a new attribute to existing attribute sets which already contain configurable products

Tags: magento, attributes

I need to add an attribute to an existing set of products which are already within an attribute set. When I go into the product after adding the neww attribute to the attribute set I can't see it in the product edit page?

Is there any way to do this? maybe at database level? or an I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Dave

**edit - sorry forgot to mention these are configurable products that the new attribute isn't working on**

Comment: what version of magento? are the products configurable? did you set up the attribute correctly?

Comment: magento 1.5.1.0, they are all setup correctly and sorry I forgot to mention they are configurable products. I do have simple products also which seem to have accepted the addition attruibte fine. I take it configurables cant accept new attributes?

Comment: Did you do it programmatically or just using the backend? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. What you might want to try is changing the group that the attribute is in, from prices to description and then see if it shows up on the description pane.

Comment: I've already tried moving the attribute to another pane (incase I was simply just not seeing it) but doesn't seem to be registering? As mentioned above, I forgot to mention they are configurable products.

Comment: With your attribute did you set it to be applicable to all product types? I just did a test of adding a simple 'text field' attribute to an existing set, opened a product and it showed up. The attribute not being applicable to configurable/simple products is the only step I saw along the way where you could have made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reindex your Data?
System -> Index Management